# react redux state mangment with redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

[link to code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-waterfall-v543e?file=/src/components/Product.js)

i i'm trying to update state with redux not able to achieve it you can say as beginner level problem what i done till now is when i dispatch action it update the store and from store i want to access the entire store and its length to i'm trying all this in ecommerce web site
when i dispatch the action it update the store and i'm able to see result but it showing odd result which i don't want when i try access length some time is take length of product id length say if product id have 4 digit than it show length 4 and if i added two time it show length equal to 8
here is code

```
// appslice.js file
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const appSlice = createSlice({
    name: "basket",
    initialState: {
        baskets: [],
        value: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        incremented: (state, action) => {
            // console.log("state from appslice>>", state.baskets);
            console.log("state from appslice>>", action);
            // state.baskets += action.payload.price;
            state.baskets += action.payload;
        },
        basketvalue: (state) => {
            state.value = state.basket.length;
        },
        decremented: (state, action) => {
            state.basket -= action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { incremented, decremented } = appSlice.actions;
export const selectbasket = (state) => state.baskets;
export const value = (state) => state.value;

export default appSlice.reducer;
```

```
// store.js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import appreducer from "../appSlice";
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: appreducer,
});

export default store;
```

```
// home.js file
import Product from "./Product";
<Product
  id="12321341"
  title="title here"
  price={11.96}
  rating={5}
  image={images go here}
/>
```

```
// product.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { incremented, selectbasket, value } from "../redux/appSlice";
import "./product.css";

function Product({ id, title, image, price, rating }) {
    let dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log("selectbasket", selectbasket);
    // let basketvalues = useSelector(selectbasket);
    let values = useSelector(value);
    let addtostore = () => {
        dispatch(incremented({ id, title, image, price, rating }));
    };

    return (
        <div className="product">
            {/* {console.log("valuess>>>>", values)} */}
            <div className="product__info">
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p className="product__price">
                    <small>$</small>
                    <strong>{price}</strong>
                </p>
                <div className="product__rating">
                    {/* //making Array */}
                    {Array(rating)
                        .fill()
                        .map((_, i) => (
                            <p></p>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src={image} alt="" />
            <button onClick={addtostore}>Add to Basket</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Product;
```

```
// header.js here i want to show length of array in header.js
import React from "react";
import "./header.css";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ShoppingCartIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCart";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { basketvalue, selectbasket } from "../redux/appSlice";

let image = window.location.origin + "/images/amazon_logo.png";

function Header() {
    let basket = useSelector(selectbasket);
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <Link to="/">
                <img className="header__logo" src={image} alt="amazon_logo" />
            </Link>
            <div className="header__search">
                <input type="text" className="header__searchInput" />
                <SearchIcon className="header__searchIcon" />
            </div>
            <div className="header__nav">
                <div className="header__option">
                    <span className="header__optionLineOne">hello, guest</span>
                    <span className="header__optionLineTwo">signin</span>
                </div>
                <div className="header__option">
                    <span className="header__optionLineOne">Return</span>
                    <span className="header__optionLineTwo">& order</span>
                </div>
                <div className="header__option">
                    <span className="header__optionLineOne">Your</span>
                    <span className="header__optionLineTwo">Prime</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Link to="/checkout">
                <div className="header__optionBasket ">
                    <ShoppingCartIcon />
                    <span className="header__optionLineTwo header__basketCount">
                        {console.log("basket>>>", { basket })}
                        {basket?.length}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

```
// checkout page here i want to access complet store with all its value
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectbasket, value } from "../redux/appSlice";
import "./checkout.css";
import Subtotal from "./subtotal";
let images = window.location.origin + "/images/amazon_ad.jpg";
function Checkout() {
    let basket = useSelector(selectbasket);
    let values = useSelector(value);
    return (
        <div className="checkout">
            {console.log("valuess>>>>", values?.length)}
            <div className="checkout_left">
                <img src={images} alt="checkout_ad" className="checkout_ad" />
                <h2 className="checkout_title">your shopping basket</h2>
                {console.log("basket from checkout >>>", basket)}
                {basket}
            </div>
            <div className="checkout_right">
                <Subtotal />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to help with issues like this if you format your code - I'd recommend using Prettier.io. With it all bundled up and indented irregularly it's difficult to quickly scan it for potential issues.

Comment: ok i'm sharing codesandbox link...

Answer (score 2):

Since baskets is supposed to be an array of object based on your implementation, you would need to handle the addition operation like you are doing it for an array by pushing to it instead of using the `addition operator` which would convert object to string and the array to string and concat the two strings

You implementation will look like

```
 incremented: (state, action) => {
        // console.log("state from appslice>>", state.baskets);
        console.log("state from appslice>>", action);
        // push payload object to the array of baskets
        state.baskets.push(action.payload);
    },
```

Similar thing needs to be done for decremented function too.

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-solomon-598s5?file=/src/components/Checkout.js)

Comment: i have already try that but it show error not a function i also added a codesand box link in Question and when you click on add to basket see the changes at top right corner

Comment: I modified your codeesandbox and included a working sample inn my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you're facing is with your reducers. There are two big issues with them. First off, two of your reducers make changes to `state.basket` and the third makes changes to `state.baskets`. But the more concerning error is using += and -= with an array value.

```js
let arr = []
arr += {a: 4}
console.debug(arr) // Prints "[object Object]"
```

+= clearly doesn't do what you were aiming for (you probably want `concat` instead). -= is even more tricky because you seem to be assuming it will find a value equal to the payload and remove it, but equality is notoriously slippery in Javascript when dealing with non-primitive values like Object.

I think you need to rethink how you're trying to manipulate your state here and figure out another way to do append and remove using the [available functions on Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or by changing your user's basket to an Object-like data structure. Once you have it working on the console, then you can try porting it into Redux (since the rest of your Redux actually looks pretty spot-on).

Comment: if don't do that **+=** it show only current state where as i want current and previous state.

Comment: @vibhu I don't fully understand what you're saying, but I'd look below at Shubham's suggestion. You need to mutate state.baskets but you have to do it in a way that actually works in Javascript. += doesn't append an object to an array, so you have to figure out how to do that append differently.

Comment: i already added link to code sandbox hope you understand what i try to say... please go through the link once and see the change when you click on add to basket button